# Who was the guy in the B-52's video "Roam"?

Tags: rock, music-video

In the music video Roam by the B-52's there appears to be an African American B-52 with large hair (not really an Afro but similarly large).

Upon seeing that I though "Oh, cool, the B-52s were more diverse than I thought" but then when I checked out the Wikipedia article to find out who he was I didn't see any African-American B-52 listed.

Who was that guy?

[image]

Comment: Ok but who is he? He also in the love shack video but he does not look remotely like any of the main members I've seen pictured on Wikipedia or elsewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It Iooks like its Zachary 'Zack' Alford, a professional drummer known for his work in the Saturday Night Live Band, as well as with Bruce Springsteen and David Bowie.
According to the biography on his website, zachalford.com, he played for the B52s in 1989. This was the year the B52s album 'Cosmic Thing' was produced, from which the single Roam was taken.

Comment: Good find!  And I stand corrected, it looks like Zack is indeed African-American.